# How to Recompile Invalid Java Class Objects in SYS user in an Oracle 10g DB?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I need to upgrade an ORACLE 10g db to 11g, but have tons invalid JAVA CLASS object type objects in an user schema, and 30 invalid JAVA CLASS object type objects in SYS schema, and I read some doc, you should not have any invalid objects in SYS schema prior to the upgrade, but I ran the recompile all objects script utlrp.sql already, those invalid objects (object type is JAVA CLASS) are persistent in both the user and SYS schema. So can I go ahead to upgrade the db? Or how can I get rid of those invalid JAVA CLASS object type objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to My Oracle Support?

Looks like MOS Doc ID 464568.1 may have some good information for you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Good meta link note. I went ahead upgraded the db regardless those sys invalid objects (most of them are java class type), and Oracle upgrade group expert told me by upgrading the db from 10g to 11g, it may get rid of some of those invalid objects(JAVA Class type) in sys which turned out true, but only got rid of 4 of them among 144 of them during upgrade the db. I will try to drop them according the meta link note in the future... thanks!

Comment: Lame answer - what if you don't have access to MOS?

Comment: I understand...but that's where I found the answer, and I don't think pasting the solution here, from a note that requires an Oracle Support subscription, would be kosher.  If you have any freely available solution, feel free to post it.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
alter java class "*Your Class Name Goes Here*" resolve;
```